# How to fix this error ? “ 'unicode' object has no attribute 'tzinfo' ” using MySql

Tags: django

I am currently using MySQL on my project. When i try to edit a table from django admin end i get these error AttributeError at /admin/workAdmin/airwaybill/1/.

How do i go about it

Answer (score 0):

You could try to load the timezone definitions:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo/ | mysql -u root mysql -p

mysql> select count(*) from `mysql`.`time_zone_name`;
flush tables;
```